# Sinatra on Nginx configuration - what's wrong?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra

I followed [this](http://tommy.chheng.com/index.php/2009/06/deploying-a-sinatra-app-on-nginx-passenger-with-capistrano-and-git/) tutorial more or less... I installed the passenger gem, executed passenger-install-ginx-module, sucessfully installed nginx and inserted this into the config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /home/admin/sintest/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

In /home/admin/sintest I have: an empty public folder,
the config.ru:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :env,  :production
disable :run

require './app.rb'    #the app itself

run Sinatra::Application
```

and a test sinatra app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "hello world!"
end
```

Now when I run nginx and open up http://localhost what I get is: 403 Forbidden

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the user nginx is running as (in most cases 'nobody' or 'www-data') has permission to read the contents of your home directory /home/admin.

Also you can look into the nginx logs and read exactly what the error was.

Comment: 2010/09/14 18:36:04 [error] 12131#0: *2 "/home/admin/sintest/public/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost" in the error.log... but it should evaluate the url with sinatra? thats the whole point of passenger?

Comment: I was not aware that nginx runs as nobody as default... ok I fixed it... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error until I added passenger_root and passenger_ruby directives in the http block.